# Graeme West's VBA code Monotone Convex

Tags: quantlib, yield-curve, interpolation

Can somebody post Graeme West's VBA code for monotone convex interpolation if you have? I was struggling to find it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not on topic for QSE.

Comment: This is used for interpolating treasury yield curve and related to quantitative finance

Comment: I don't know about this code but maybe @luigiballabio knows, [see this GH issue](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/490).

Comment: Can you comment on why this is useful for yield curve interpolation? Or provide any references about it?

Comment: It's used for Treasury yield curve construction. It has references in the Treasury website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by Bob in the comments, if you follow the github issue, you'll get the link to the Graeme West's Excel sheet for monotone convex interpolation. The link is now dead, but a quick search on web arxiv you could get a historical saved version of the sheet with this [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20180903055110/finmod.co.za/Monotone%20Convex%20Interpolation.xls). You should be able to get the VBA codes from here, assuming it is actually Graeme West's work.

Comment: Thank you for your search. Are you able to download this excel workbook?

Comment: Great . Thank you for this. I was able to download it.

Comment: @SaratMuppana Please click the check mark to accept this answer.